# check and compare value entered in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA in Excel 2010. I was wondering if there is a simple way to check to see if the value entered in the combobox matches the already populated value within the combobox.

```
Private Sub cmbMonth_Enter() With Me.cmbMonth .AddItem "January" .AddItem "February" .AddItem "March" .AddItem "April" .AddItem "May" .AddItem "June" .AddItem "July" .AddItem "August" .AddItem "September" .AddItem "October" .AddItem "November" .AddItem "December" End With End Sub
```

As you can see, this combobox is populated with the values of the names of the months. What I would like to do is, if the user manually types in a month and misspells it, on exit, check and see if what they entered matches with what is in the combobox, if not display a message box.

Thank you.

Comment: Every time you enter your combobox the list will be added with 12 more months. Fill your ComboBox in the form.initialize event. Instead of catching a wrong typo, I would suggest to change your cmbMonth.Style to 2-frmStyleDropDownList, this way the user has to select and no errors can be made.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it **and** highlight the misspelled entry **and** reset the focus to the combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim val As Variant
    With Me.ComboBox1 ' rename, if necessary
        val = .Value
        If .ListIndex = -1 And val <> vbNullString Then
            Cancel = True
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(val)
            Debug.Print "Illegal entry!" ' remove in production or replace with MsgBox
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```